# Python returning letter in product *possible project euler#8 spoiler*

Tags: python-2.7

So I was doing question 8 on project euler (https://projecteuler.net/problem=8),
and my code was:

```
def prodcheck (n, count):
    digs = []
    a = str (n)
    for dig in a:
        digs.append (int (dig))
    n = 0
    prod = 1
    prodset = []
    while n < len (digs):
        prod = 1
        for num in digs [n: n + count + 1]:
            prod *= num
        prodset.append (prod)
        n += 1
    return max(prodset)
```

and after copying in the huge block number line by line, I got a weird number with a letter as a product(specifically 70573265280L, should have been all numbers), can anyone tell me what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

letter 'L' at the end of int means long. You should be able to use it normally in other equations as any other number because Python fully supports mixed arithmetic. You can also trim trailing L cause its for informational purpose. So in this case the answer is 70573265280.

For more information about numeric types please visit [python documentation page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex).